# what is the corresponding projected coordinate system to WGS84?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Global DEM to Slope calculation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14750/global-dem-to-slope-calculation)

I want to calculate the slope from my global DEM?the DEM has WGS84 projection(degrees).In order to correctly calculate the slope from DEM,it has to be projected coordinate system not geographic coordinate system.it is really difficult to say which one of the  projections under the list :
projected coordinate systems is the corresponding to WGS84(world) under the list geographic coordinate systems.Any ideas?