# Uninstalling/reinstalling QGIS plugin where uninstall is disabled?

Tags: qgis-plugins, installation, qgis-2

Plugin Raster->TerrainAnalysis->slope which **had** initially worked, started showing what another questioner referred to as a "crazy histogram":
[Slope analysis from NED data gives crazy histogram?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79803/qgis2-slope-analysis-from-ned-data-gives-crazy-histogram)

Before finding his question and the answer, I endeavored to uninstall and reinstall the plugin.

I found/still find (QGIS 2.0.1, now upgraded to QGIS 2.4, on Ubuntu 14.04), the plugin "uninstall" button grayed out/disabled.

It's working, but I am worried about having a plugin I installed that does not offer an option to be uninstalled.

Failing anything else I would be tempted to use the path information to rename the .so library and see if it disappeared.

[image: uninstall grayed-out]

Answer (score 5):

This plugin is a C++ core plugin and cannot be uninstalled. Only Python plugins can be uninstalled. If you find an issue with a core plugin which is reproducible, please report the bug.