# QGIS/GDALDEM SLOPE Output Has Contoured Or Terraced Texture

Tags: qgis, contour, slope, gdaldem, texture

I have been trying to greatly reduce or eliminate the contour-like texture that appears in my output from `gdaldem slope`.  The image, below, demonstrates this textural effect.

[image: Output from <code>gdaldem slope</code>, demonstrating the textural effect I am trying to reduce]

The texture of the slope values appears to follow the contours, making a terraced effect.  I am curious, does this output reflect a reasonable calculation of slope (e.g. reasonable isoclines)? Or are these patterns an artifact?

Is it possible that I will not be able to eliminate this effect because this texture is present in the original DEM (image, below)?

[image]

I have tried a number of suggestions for reducing patterns in the slope values, for instance:

- warping (reprojecting) the DEM so that the vertical units match the horizontal units (as suggested in [Slope analysis from NED data gives crazy histogram?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79803/slope-analysis-from-ned-data-gives-crazy-histogram))
- warping (reprojecting) the DEM, as above, but using different resampling methods (as suggested in [What is the source of horizontal and vertical striping in USGS DEMs?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107477/what-is-the-source-of-horizontal-and-vertical-striping-in-usgs-dems))
- using various "ratio of vertical units to horizontal" values in `gdaldem slope` (e.g. 111120 or 370400, as suggested in [Getting incorrect slope values from an ASTER DEM in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143139/getting-incorrect-slope-values-from-an-aster-dem-in-qgis))

Also, I have seen this texture in many other slope rasters, see for example:

- aldo_tapia's Slope results in [Hillshade shows grid texture artifacts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271439/hillshade-shows-grid-texture-artifacts/279817#279817))
- [This link](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/imagery/understanding-curvature-rasters/?rmedium=redirect&rsource=blogs.esri.com%2Fesri%2Farcgis%2F2010%2F10%2F27%2Funderstanding-curvature-rasters) to a blog about Curvature

Any ideas on what causes this?

Comment: Similar to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140026/getting-strange-grid-artifacts-when-creating-hillshades-using-gdaldem/140062#140062 perhaps, where did your DEM come from? Is it interpolated from contours?

Comment: The DEM was obtained in an *.adf format from the National Map download utility and is identified as "U.S. Geological Survey, 2013, USGS NED n41w125 1/3 arc-second 2013 1 x 1 degree ArcGrid: U.S. Geological Survey." I warped/projected the DEM from NAD83 (EPSG 4269) into UTM Zone 10N (EPSG 21690) so the horizontal and vertical units would be consistent. The DEM was not interpolated from contours, so the 'gdal_grid' algorithm wasn't used and it would be unclear to me if the question you refer to is similar.