# How to make slope map from elevation map in Lat/Long?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, elevation, latitude-longitude, slope

I have an elevation raster map of the world, in Lat/Long. When I make a slope map, the results of the raster cells will be either 0, or values close to 90. The problem seems to be that the Slope function does not understand the horizontal units (which is obviously degrees, but should be meters). How can I solve this? I am using ArcGIS.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please be sure to take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).  Please also remember to include the version of GIS software in use with each question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reproject the raster file to a metric coordinate system, e.g.  Lambert azimuthal equal-area projection. As ArcGIS always uses the same units (degree or meters) for vertical and horizontal measures.

You can use the toolbox:

```
Data Management Tools -> Projections and Transformations -> Raster -> Project Raster
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where can I find the Lambert projection? Would Mercator also be fine?

Comment: I guess so, as long as it has metric units. You could also use Cylindrical Equal Area for example. After you're finished you can project back to whatever your previous reference system was, I am guessing WGS84

Comment: I would NOT use Mercator for calculations BY ITSELF. Global Slope calculations are not so simple. I would read through the second answer found here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14750/how-to-use-srtm-global-dem-for-slope-calculation before moving forward.

Comment: That's why I originally suggested Lambert azimuthal equal-area. My answer was not focussing on the best reference system needed for global slope calculation it mainly focused on here error and the solution to it. But thanks for the great link!